# What is an example of a meager space X such that X is concentrated on countable dense set?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

A topological space $X$ is concentrated on a set $D$ iff for any open set $G$ if $D\subseteq G$, then $X\setminus G$ is countable.

What is an example of a separable metrizable (uncountable) meager (meaning a countable union of nowhere dense subsets, also known as a set of first category) space $X$ such that $X$ is concentrated on countable dense set?

Comment: I agree, but perhaps there is an example not as a subset of the reals ?

Comment: $X$ is meager as a topological space.

Comment: Given that you want an example that is not a subset of $\mathbb R$, maybe you should change "A set of reals $X$" to "A topological space $X$" in the first sentence?

Comment: @PierrePC: Let $K_1$ be the usual middle-thirds Cantor set.  Let $K_2$ be a Cantor set where instead of removing the middle third of each interval, you remove the middle 1/9.  We have $K_1 \subset K_2$ and I think you can show that $K_1$ is nowhere dense in $K_2$.  Let $K_3$ be the Cantor set where you remove the middle 1/27, and so on.  Then $X = \bigcup_n K_n$ is uncountable, and each $K_n$ is nowhere dense in $X$.

Comment: If such $X$ exists, it must be a "monster" that requires the axiom of choice to construct.  The Cantor set is not concentrated on a countable set, so therefore $X$ does not contain a homeomorphic copy of the Cantor set.  This means that if $X$ is embedded into any Polish space (such as its completion $\overline{X}$), it will be a subset that lacks the perfect set property.

Comment: The classic example of a set without the PSP is the Bernstein set, but it doesn't work because it is not meager in its relative topology ([Lemma 6 of these notes](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/bernstein-set/)).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**ADDED LATER**

The answer to your question is that there is such a space $X$ if and only if $\mathfrak{b} = \aleph_1$.

*If $\mathfrak{b} = \aleph_1$, then there is such a space.*

To see this, first note that $\mathfrak{b} = \aleph_1$ if and only if there is an uncountable subset of the irrationals concentrated on $\mathbb Q$. This is proved by van Douwen in section 10 of his article in the *Handbook of Set Theoretic Topology*. By modifying his argument slightly, we can show that if $\mathfrak{b} = \aleph_1$ then there is an uncountable subset of the Cantor space concentrated on a countable subset of the Cantor space.

[The proof of this goes as follows. If $\mathfrak{b} = \aleph_1$, then one can construct via transfinite recursion a length-$\omega_1$ sequence $\langle f_\alpha :\, \alpha < \omega_1 \rangle$ of functions that is unbounded with respect to $\leq^*$, but also with the property that $\alpha < \beta$ implies $f_\alpha \leq^* f_\beta$. This means that a subset of this sequence is $\leq^*$-bounded if and only if it is countable. It's a well-known fact that the space $\omega^\omega$, endowed with the usual product topology, is homeomorphic to the space of irrational numbers. It is also fairly well known that the irrationals are homeomorphic to $C \setminus D$, where $C$ is the Cantor space and $D$ is some countable relatively dense subset of $C$. Let $Y$ be the image of your sequence of functions under some homeomorphism $\omega^\omega \rightarrow C \setminus D$. If $U$ is an open set containing $D$, then $C \setminus U$ is a compact subset of $C$. It's not too difficult to show that every compact subset of $\omega^\omega$ is $\leq^*$-bounded above by some function (or even more -- it is $\leq$-bounded), and this means $C \setminus U$ contains only countably many points of $Y$.]

Let $Y$ be, as in the previous paragraph, an $\aleph_1$-sized subset of the Cantor space $C$ that concentrates on a countable $D \subseteq  C$. Let $X = Y \cup \mathbb Q$. As a subspace of the reals, this set $X$ meets all your requirements.

*A proof that if there is a space $X$ as described in your post then $\mathfrak{b} = \aleph_1$.*

Suppose there is an uncountable separable metrizable space $X$ that is concentrated on a countable set $D \subseteq X$. Let $\{ d_0, d_1, d_2, \dots \}$ be an enumeration of $D$. For each $x \in X \setminus D$, define a function $f_x : \omega \rightarrow \omega$ by setting $f_x(n) = \min\{ k :\, \mathrm{dist}(x,d_n) > \frac{1}{k} \}$.

Let $Y$ be a subset of $X \setminus D$ with $|Y| = \aleph_1$. The set of functions $\{ f_x :\, x \in Y \}$ is an $\aleph_1$-sized subset of $\omega^\omega$, and I claim it is unbounded with respect to $\leq^*$. In other words, I claim this set of functions witnesses $\mathfrak{b} = \aleph_1$.

To see this, suppose instead there is some $g \in \omega^\omega$ such that $f_x \leq^* g$ for all $x \in Y$. By a pigeonhole argument, there is some function $h \in \omega^\omega$, differing from $g$ in only finitely many places, such that $f_x \leq h$ for uncountably many $x \in Y$. Let $U = \bigcup_{n \in \omega} B_{1/h(n)}(d_n)$. This is an open set containing $D$, and our definition of the $f_x$'s ensures that $x \notin U$ if and only if $f_x \leq h$. Thus there are uncountable many $x$'s with $x \notin U$, contradicting the fact that $Y$ concentrates on $D$.

Let me point out that this argument is essentially contained in an earlier MO post by Taras Banakh found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416331/example-of-an-uncountable-scattered-space-with-some-properties). (A version of the argument seems to be in van Douwen's article too, and I don't know whether it really originated there either, but anyway I first learned it from Taras' post.)

$$$$

**ORIGINAL POST**

Here is a consistent example of a subspace of $\mathbb R$ with these properties.

First, there is an uncountable subset $X$ of $\mathbb R$ concentrating on $\mathbb Q$ if and only if $\mathfrak{b} = \aleph_1$. This is proved in chapter 10 of van Douwen's article in the *Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology*. Note that $X$ concentrates on $\mathbb Q$ if and only if every subset of $X$ does, so if $\mathfrak{b} = \aleph_1$ then there is an $\aleph_1$-sized set of reals concentrating on $\mathbb Q$.

Now suppose $\aleph_1 = \mathfrak{b} < \mathrm{non}(\mathcal M)$ (the least size of a non-meager subset of $\mathbb R$). This situation is consistent -- it happens in the random real model, for example. In such a model, let $X$ be an $\aleph_1$-sized set concentrating on $\mathbb Q$. Adding countably many points to $X$ if necessary, we may (and do) assume $X$ is dense in $\mathbb R$. Then (viewed as a subspace of $\mathbb R$) it meets all your requirements.
$$$$
*A sketch of an argument as to why $\mathfrak{b} = \aleph_1$ implies there is an $\aleph_1$-sized set concentrating on $\mathbb Q$*:

Since you may not have access to van Douwen's article, here is a sketch of the idea I quoted above. If $\mathfrak{b} = \aleph_1$, then one can construct via transfinite recursion a length-$\omega_1$ sequence $\langle f_\alpha :\, \alpha < \omega_1 \rangle$ of functions that is unbounded with respect to $\leq^*$, but also has the property that $\alpha < \beta$ implies $f_\alpha \leq^* f_\beta$. It's a well-known fact that the space $\omega^\omega$, endowed with the usual product topology, is homeomorphic to the space of irrational numbers. Let $X$ be the image of your sequence of functions under any such homeomorphism. If $U$ is an open set containing $\mathbb Q$, then $\mathbb R \setminus U$ is a $\sigma$-compact subset of the irrationals. It's not too difficult to show that every $\sigma$-compact subset of $\omega^\omega$ is $\leq^*$-bounded above by some function, and this means $\mathbb R \setminus U$ can only contain countably many points of $X$.

Comment: Actually, thinking about this a bit more, I think it's possible to show that $\mathfrak{b} = \aleph_1$ if there is an uncountable separable metric space concentrating on a countable set. So consistency is the best you can hope for. (My guess is that $\mathfrak{b} = \aleph_1$ is the optimal hypothesis -- the other thing is just to make the "meager" part easy.) I will come back tomorrow to write out the details of this, but I can't at the moment because I'm about to attend a seminar, and then head home for the day :)

Comment: Dear Will, as always a complete and wonderful answer! Thanks!

Comment: Will there be a dense set $S$ in $X$ such that $S\subset \mathbb{Q}$ and $S$ is $G_{\delta}$ ?

Comment: @AlexanderOsipov: There can be. In the modified argument that I just posted, which gets rid of the requirement that $\mathrm{non}(\mathcal M)$ be larger than $\mathfrak{b}$, the set $\mathbb Q \setminus C$ is relatively $G_\delta$ in $X$, and it is dense in $X$ as well.

Comment: A topological space $X$ is $\kappa$-concentrated on a set $D$ iff for any open set $G$ if $D\subseteq G$, then $|X\setminus G|<\kappa$. Then,  I think it's possible to show that $b=\kappa$ if there is an uncountable separable metric space $\kappa$-concentrating on a countable set.  I think this is just a generalization of your proof.

Comment: @AlexanderOsipov: Yes, I think you're right.

Comment: @AlexanderOsipov: I don't know -- good question though.

Comment: @WillBrain: I think you will be interested in the article   arxiv.org/pdf/1603.03361

Comment: @AlexanderOsipov This is Lemma 2.3 in the paper "Products of Menger spaces: A combinatorial approach" ( https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2016.08.002 ). In particular, if you use a b-scale, it is both meager and null and b-concentrated on the rationals of the Cantor space.

Comment: @WillBrian see my comment for Sasha

Comment: @BoazTsaban: Thanks! It looks like an interesting paper too.